# Framework not found EXAV in Notification Extension while building React Native Project

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting this error `Framework not found EXAV` while running [RocketChat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative) on Xcode14.2.

But this image processing framework is already available on this path `node_modules/expo-av/ios/EXAV`.

Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using MacBook on Apple Silicon.

You should go to "Build Settings" and add x86_64 under Excluded architectures for Debug or for Release too(the picture shows only for debug), after doing it, Xcode won't try to build the x86_64 version of the app and it won't crash.

[image]

After that, it will only build the app for arm64 and since your simulator is also arm64, it will work fine.

Please note, that if you push changes to your remote git repository and another coworker will try to build with intel MacBook, he will get errors, since intel MacBooks have x86_64 simulators.

Good luck!